# AK suited in the BB

Tags: nlhe, tournament, betting-strategy

This hand was one of the hand day reviews by a pro

$50 / $100
**first** hand of tournament
everyone starts with 300 BB

Hero BB  A♠ K♠

```
HJ    $250   
CO    $250  
BB   $1050   
      fold  
      call     
pot  $2400
```

Flop K⋄ 5♣  5♥

```
BB bet $1300  
CO call
```

Turn  6♠

```
check  
check
```

River J♥

```
 $3600 
$10000
  call (getting 2.5:1)
```

**What do you think of the play?**

> CO shows 55 and takes down the pot

Answer (score 1):

I think he played his hand completely fine.

His flop bet was a little large, but they were quite deep, so I don't mind. He has a very strong hand and will be bluffing this flop a ton. It makes a lot of sense to include value in his range as well.

Turn check is a little strange, but you have to realise hero will be bluffing the flop a lot. Protecting his check range every once in a while with a strong king in this spot makes a lot of sense.

River bet is fine as well. You can get value with your strong kings and mix in some good bluffs. Getting raised is very tricky, but his call is completely fine. Out of all the kings he has in his range, AK is obviously the strongest one. Hero doesn't really have a 5, so he is capped. If he is folding AK he is folding 100% of his range. Besides, the only thing villain is really representing is pocket 5s and 6s. Folding AK is exploitable. He played his hand very well.

Update:

You can make an argument for calling some of your AK's and folding others. There is a small chance villain had a backdoor flush draw on the flop and now turned it into a bluff. There wasn't a spade on the flop so AsKs is the only combination perfect for a call. AsKs HAS to be in your calling range. I would never fold AK here, but you have to call with all of your AK's containing at least one spade.

Comment: "if folding AK, then folding 100% of range." would this mean you are shoving KK, JJ? Would A5s bet the turn?

Answer (score 0):

I won't accept my own answer.

This was posted by a pro I like but don't agree with his line on this one.

**Pre**
I like it. The raise is giving them 2:1 to call.  If you scoop the pot great but AKs is strong and plays OK out of position.

**Flop**
Great flop for you.  Like 85% you are ahead. I don't like bet over 1/2 the pot.  First hand so you have an open slate. You are way ahead or way behind. Villain should have 3 bet pre with AA KK. 5 is in villain's range 55, 45s, 56s. Villain could be on weaker K or smaller pocket pair. QJs would hang around. I would bet 1/3 ($800) for value. I feel like you may fold out some hands you dominate. If they are on trips then go for pot control.

**Turn**
If they are on 66 then that is poker.  Given you over bet pre I am OK with check but I think you should have packaged it like $800 flop $1600 turn.  Yes you might have lost more but KK is usually good here.

**River**
JJ most likely would have 3 bet pre.  KK still looks good here.  You could get called by TT, 99, 88, 77, KQs?   I like the open bet.  When you get raised wow.  It is hard to get away but 55 makes sense.  I get 55 checking the turn as they need you to think the K is good.  If villain bets turn you may check the river.

Comment: What exactly did you not like about the play, except for flop bet-sizing? What is the point you are trying to make with this question/answer?

Comment: what exactly did you not like about the play? In my opinion it was played very well and I don't see a reason for posting it. Not trying to offend you, just curious.